# Echo/Printf environment key/value upon creation

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, bash4

I'm using bash 4, and setting a few vars (each beginning `MIH_`) similar to:

```
: "${MIH_POD_NAME:=$(kubectl get pods --namespace mih -l "app.kubernetes.io/name=mih,app.kubernetes.io/instance=mih" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")}"
```

I want to know if its possible to print the details of these environment variable to stdout inline as they're created, rather than having to create them all, then separately iterate over them afterwards, using:

```
for var in "${!MIH_@}"; do
   logger $(printf '%s=%s\n' "$var" "${!var}")
done
```

Output:

```
INFO  MIH_POD_NAME=mih-8695f87c8c-t5klb
```

(Note, `logger` is a function I've written that takes a string and formats it for a nice output.)

Adding an `echo` before the `:` only prints the value after a colon:
`: mih-8695f87c8c-t5klb`

---

I managed to achieve this somewhat by adding:

```
; eval "logger $(printf '%s=%s\n' MIH_POD_NAME $MIH_POD_NAME)"
```

to the end of each command.  But I wonder if there is a more dynamic way of achieving this?

Comment: Did you try using  **[`declare`](https://linuxhint.com/bash_declare_command/)** command?

Comment: `logger is a function I've written that takes a string and formats it for a nice output` The command [logger](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html) is already a super useful and super old Linux logging utility, I would guess available everywhere nowadays. Consider renaming your function.

Comment: Better ideas below, but you could also wrap your block of declarations with `set -x ; VAR=... ; VAR2=...; set +x` (or even `set -vx ... ; set +vx`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of **[`declare`](https://linuxhint.com/bash_declare_command/)** to achieve your purpose.

We can use an associative array option(`-A`) to store the variable names as keys and the corresponding commands as values. Something like:

```bash
declare -A MIH_VARS=(
  ["MIH_POD_NAME"]="kubectl get pods --namespace mih -l 'app.kubernetes.io/name=mih,app.kubernetes.io/instance=mih' -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}'"
  ["MIH_VAR_1"]="echo '8080'"
  ["MIH_VAR_2"]="cmd_to_get_other_port_no"
)

for var in "${!MIH_VARS[@]}"; do
  declare -g "${var}=$(${MIH_VARS[$var]})"
  logger "$(declare -p ${var})"
done
```

**[DEMO](https://onlinegdb.com/HvTN_76X6T)**

Comment: This assumes that the command to set each variable is identical, which seems unlikely in the OP's scenario.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this @mandy8055.  Yes, the vars are set with different commands, some are gathering port numbers etc.

Comment: Lovely! This is exactly what I was after, thanks a lot @mandy8055